# Full Text Near with Max Distance Syntax in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

I'm trying to write a full text search using a near proximity term with a max distance.

From what I can tell of the grammer...

```
    <custom_proximity_term> ::= 
  NEAR ( 
     {
        { <simple_term> | <prefix_term> } [ ,…n ]
     |
        ( { <simple_term> | <prefix_term> } [ ,…n ] ) 
      [, <maximum_distance> [, <match_order> ] ]
     }
       ) 

      <maximum_distance> ::= { integer | MAX }
      <match_order> ::= { TRUE | FALSE }
```

...I should be able to use `NEAR` like such:

```
'NEAR(term1,term2,5)'
```

OR

```
'NEAR((term1,term2),5)'
```

However always throws a syntax error.

```
Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition 'NEAR((term1, term2), 4, TRUE)'.
```

Even when i try to copy the exact search from a microsoft Example it throws an error:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

SELECT DocumentNode, Title, DocumentSummary
FROM Production.Document AS DocTable 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Production.Document, Document,
  'NEAR(bracket, reflector)' ) /* doesn't like this */ AS KEY_TBL
  ON DocTable.DocumentNode = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
WHERE KEY_TBL.RANK > 50
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
GO

Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition 'NEAR(bracket, reflector)'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL 2012(Denali) - The syntax can be a little confusing but if you look at the grammar closely, when using maximum_distance or match_order the terms(simple/prefix) have to be surrounded by additional parentheses.

So, to do a simple NEAR search you would use -

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Production.Document, Document, 'NEAR(bracket, reflector)')
```

and to limit the distance and/or match order you would use -

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Production.Document, Document, 'NEAR((bracket, reflector), 1, TRUE)')
```

I **just noticed** the SQL2008 tag. 'NEAR' is [handled differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in that release. What you probably want to use there is 'term1 NEAR term2'.

Comment: ahhh i just realized that i was looking at documentation for 2012.  So i'm guessing max distance isn't supported with 2008?

Comment: Right, no distance support in 2008/2008R2.